# how to load file the moment java program starts

Tags: java, drawing, draw

I created a drawing manager which gets coordinates from txt file and using some functions to draw several shapes with them. my question is how can i make a program load this sort of file automatically? in other words, how can i make a program load a txt file the moment it starts so the application will start with the shapes allready on the screen?

Comment: Please include your code and what you have tried already. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Well it depends on how you read your file, where it is, and how you process the data. But every Java-Programm starts by calling some `public static void main(String[] args)` method. Thats where you read your file, if you want it done before loading the actual windows.

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner("coordinates.txt");
    ArrayList<String> lines = new ArrayList<>(); // just something to hold the lines of the text file seperately
    while (scanner.hasNextLine()){
        lines.add(scanner.nextLine());          // read all lines of the text file
    }

    new MyMainApplicationWindow(lines);        // I don't know how you process the data in your application, so I just pass the list of lines with the constructor
}
```

Comment: A java program starts with a `main` method. That need not be your own `main` method however. E.g. applets start at a `main` method you don't write yourself, android apps too and javafx supports a startup similar to applets as far as I know.

Comment: @fabian: you are of course right. What I was trying to say is that there is always an access-point, where you can run your own initialization stuff. In Applets the method is even called `init()` in Android you have your `onCreate()` etc. But since OP didn't give any specifics I assumed a desktop Program.